# An exercise on Banach Spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

As an exercise I have to prove the set $H=\{x= (x_k):x_k∈\mathbb{C},‖x‖^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty=\frac{|x_k|^2}{k^2}<\infty\}$ to be a Banach space.

I have to prove that $H$ is complete respect to its norm.

If $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence we have for sufficiently large $n$ and $m$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|x_{n,k}-x_{m,k}|^2}{k^2} < \epsilon
$$

This implies $\{x_{n,k}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ to be convergent to $x_k \in \mathbb{C}$  for each $k$, so we can define $x=(x_k)$.

If $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converge it must converge to $x$. I have to show that $x$ is in $H$ and that it is the limit of the sequence. How do you suggest to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $M>0$ such that $\|x_n\| \leq M$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (this exists because the sequence is Cauchy). For each $N \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{|x_k|^2}{k^2} \leq M^2.
$$
This proves that $x = (x_k)$ is in $H$.

Now apply the same logic to prove that $x_n\to x$ in $H$. For each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{|x_{n,k} - x_{m,k}|^2}{k^2} \leq \|x_n - x_m\|^2 < \epsilon
$$
for all $m,n\geq N_1$, and all $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Letting $m\to \infty$ proves that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{|x_{n,k} - x_k|^2}{k^2} \leq \epsilon.
$$
This is true for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, so $\|x_n - x\| \leq \epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_1$. This proves that $x_n\to x$ in $H$.

Comment: Applying $||a-b|| \ge \left| \ ||a|| - ||b|| \  \right|$ we have $||x_n-x_m|| \ge \left| \ ||x_n|| - ||x_m| \ | \right|$, this prove that Cauchy implies bounded.

We have

$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{|x_{n,k}|^2}{k^2} \le ||x_n||^2 \le M^2
$$

Taking the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$

$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{|x_k|^2}{k^2} \le M^2
$$
Taking the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$ we got $||x||^2 \le M^2$.